# Pass constant string in ui-event focus function

Tags: angularjs, uievent

I have to call to ui-event focus function with passing input name in it or constant value..

```
<input type="password" class="form-control font-11px input-style1" ng-class="{invalid:permission.passwordRequired, valid:!permission.passwordRequired}" id="txtname" placeholder="Enter Password *" ng-model="permission.password" ui-event="{ focus : 'permission.hideErrorValidation('txtname')' }">
```

i have a function in controller

```
permission.hideErrorValidation = function (inputName) {
        console.log("Im here" + inputName);
}
```

but this prompts me error, Is there any way to add a constant value in it.
Reference : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/